# Systemd wait on a single service

Tags: boot, 16.04, services, systemd

Is it possible to create a systemd service that is run as soon as possible, and delays all other services until it finishes?

I've seen the `Type=oneshot` [option](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=), which nearly does the second part. But can you specify a service as being a dependency of all others?

I realize this might cause a slowdown; It's for a highly unusual setup.

Comment: Well you can look up which service is started first and give it a `After=yourservice.target`